# Twitter Widget Creation not working

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm following the instructions at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#customization, but after I make the widget I get `data-widget-id=""`.  There's no widget ID at all, and it can't load anything.  I've tried making different kinds of widgets as well but all of them have a blank ID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue. I created a couple of Twitter widgets two days ago, but suddenly, the generated code for all of my widgets shows: data-widget-id="".

Until Twitter fixes this, the workaround is to get the id from the URL on the page where you create the widget. It's the long number in the URL: (eg: twitter.com/settings/widgets/***[this-number-is-the-widget-id]***/edit?focus_textarea=1&notice=WIDGET_CREATED)